# firebase.json not working for ignore and cache-control

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have the following firebase.json config, but files uploaded are thousands (not the handful actually intended). Can't find place list the files, nor where they come from.

Also the cache settings are being ignored. Haven't been able to find detailed docs on grammar.

Any advice?

Here's the firebase.json file:

`{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "/",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "/ts/**",
      "/js/**",
      "/config/**",
      "package.json",
      "package-lock.json",
      "README.MD"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
        {
            "source":"*/dist/**",
            "headers":[
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"public"
                },
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"max-age=0"
                },
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"must-revalidate"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "source":"*/public/**",
            "headers":[
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"public"
                },
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"max-age=0"
                },
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"must-revalidate"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Answer: `"**/.*"` does not cover `.git/` so `"**/.git/**"` needs to be added to ignore list.

Note that cache issue was solved by including all cache-control instructions in same value.

Corrected firebase.json:

`{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "/",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/.git/**",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/ts/**",
      "**/js/**",
      "**/config/**",
      "package.json",
      "package-lock.json",
      "README.MD"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
        {
            "source":"dist/**",
            "headers":[
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"public,max-age=0,must-revalidate"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "source":"public/**",
            "headers":[
                {
                    "key":"cache-control",
                    "value":"public,max-age=0,must-revalidate"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}`